# call a function from django-form without rendering its view

Tags: django, django-forms

using Django I want to create a website on which

1. if you click a button, a function is called in the server.

And I also want a following condition:

2. after the button is clicked, the page will not to be re-rendered.

In a simpler word, I want to button-click and the run python script in the server. I've created the button-and-call-function script as follows, but it causes error because returned value is 1 and not rendering function.

How can I achieve the goal?

---

app_name/templates/app_name/index.html

```
<body>
    <form action='some_function' method='GET'>
    <button type='submit'>Click Here</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

app_name/views.py

```
def some_function(request):
    print("do something here")
    return 1 # error is caused here but I don't want re-render
```

---

app_name/url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.show_view, name='view'),
    path('do_something', views.do_something, name='do_something')
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can return for example a JsonResponse https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AJAX to run python functions asynchronously. If you want to run your python script when a button is clicked use the "onclick" event listener to call your AJAX function.

Use the URL you defined in your urls.py file and the view will get called asynchronously.

Your HTML

```
<body>
   <input type='button' value='run function' onclick='runScript()'>
</body>
```

Javascript with JQuery will provide us with an easy way to make the AJAX call

```
function runScript() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'do_something', //The URL you defined in urls.py
        success: function(data) {
          //If you wish you can do additional data manipulation here.
        }

    });
}
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_function(request):
    #Code to run
    #More code to run
    return HttpResponse('Return data to ajax call')
```

If I understood correctly you want to run python code when a button is clicked and the form's data is irrelevant.

If you are looking to actually use the form data then you may need to use e.preventDefault() in your ajax call to prevent the form from submitting and then send the data via your AJAX function.